# Conservative fields - Definition confusion

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals, greens-theorem

I have seen several definitions of conservative fields, where we always assume that the domain of a vector field $ \pmb F $ is simply connected before giving the definition of a conservative field.

**QUESTION:**

> If we find a function $ f $, where $ \pmb F = \pmb \nabla f $ , and also
>   $ \pmb F $ and $ f $ have **the same domain**, then:
>
> Can we **ignore whether the domain is simply connected or not** and label   the vector field $ \pmb F $ as conservative ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Where did you get your definitions of conservative field? I've always seen it defined for a vector field $F$ on an open set $U$, without requiring $U$ to be simply connected.The fact is that if the domain is simply connected, other common definitions are equivalent to $\nabla\times F=0$.

Comment: In any case, in the end it is a matter of choosing a definition. If your definition requires a simply connected domain then the answer to your question is *no*. But if you want to define it without requiring that condition, then the answer is *yes*.

Comment: @Javi : Actually my question derived from the following. There have been multiple questions in this website, concerning the field  $ \pmb F = ( \frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} )  $, which satisfies $curl \pmb F= \pmb 0$, but it is not conservative. The fact that this field is not conservative, is being attributed to its not simply connected domain. So is this explanation enough? Shouldn't we justify that, by saying that that $ \pmb F $ and $f$, where $\pmb F = \nabla f $ (here $ f(x,y) = \arctan \frac{y}{x}+c$), do not have the same domain?

Comment: That explanation is enough because is goes right to the definition (and if you want the necessity of simply connectedness to have the equivalence with the definition involving an scalar field).

Comment: But, as I said, it is possible to forget about simply connectedness. In that case your explanation is better and it's an example of $curl F=0$ not being equivalent to $F$ being conservative (under some other definition) when the domain is not simply connected.